# How to install R package dependencies globally on Linux?

Tags: r, linux, dependencies

I'm facing a problem where an specific R script (it just calls a `install.packages` in a package maintained by a coworker) when ran with my standard user gives me that output: `[1] "dependencies ‘methods’, ‘utils’, ‘tools’, ‘stats’, ‘grDevices’ are not available"`.

So I installed those packages using the package manager of my system with `# zypper in R-methods R-utils R-tools R-stats R-grDevices`.

When I run again it keeps giving me the same error but if I do it with sudo permissions the script just runs with no problem.

My R installation is at `/usr/lib64/R/`, and I'm using OpenSuse Tumbleweed.

So my question is how to make the R packages I just installed via the system package manager be available to every user, instead of only root.

Comment: Something is somewhat wrong with your setup---those are _all base R packages_ that should have come with R itself.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel do you sugest anything for me to do? I'm not experienced with R

Comment: Maybe you are just missing an additonal package also offered by OpenSuse. I would not know. We cannot tell from you posted.